# Validate Nova on multiple unique fields

Tags: validation, laravel-nova

I've created a Nova resource whose underlying model links to itself as a parent. I need a validation rule where the text is unique per parent ID.

```
id  text  parent_id
1   A     NULL
2   B     NULL
3   C     NULL
4   D     1
5   E     1
6   F     2
```

So, if I want to create a new item with `text:C`, `parent_id:NULL`, I can't because `id:3` already has `text:C`, `parent_id:NULL`.

If I want to update the text of `id:5` to `D`, I can't because `id:4` already has `text:D`, `parent_id:1`.

There doesn't seem to be a way to access the database from within a validation rule.

I've tried creating a Rule, then getting the `route()`, but it returns an `Illuminate\Http\Request`, not a `Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest`, from which I'd be able to get the underlying model, and then build a query.

How can I validate complex rules such as these against the database?

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        Text::make('Text')
            ->rules(Rule::unique('tablename')->where(function ($query) use($request) {

                return $query->where('text', $request->text)
                    ->where('parent_id', $request->parent_id);
        })),
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. No matter how I set the data, this rule never gets triggered.

Comment: Can you show your code ? Also can you show me the values are testing, the output & the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this.

> creationRules('unique:TABLENAME,text,NULL,id,parent_id,'.$request->Parent)
>               ->updateRules('unique:TABLENAME,text,{{resourceId}},id,parent_id,' .$request->Parent),

and you need to created the migration like this

```
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('text');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id'); 
        $table->unique(['text','parent_id']);
```

this is and example of my resource

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{

    return [

        // unique:models,name,NULL,id,company_id,
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        BelongsTo::make('Pais','Pais',\App\nova\Pais::class),

        Text::make('Provincia','nombre')->sortable()
        ->rules('required','min:2','max:30')
        ->creationRules('unique:provincias,nombre,NULL,id,pais_id,'.$request->Pais)
        ->updateRules('unique:provincias,nombre,{{resourceId}},id,pais_id,' .$request->Pais),


        BelongsTo::make('Estado')
    ];
}
```